# Find a sum with prompt. Stop when user gives -1

Tags: javascript, sum, prompt

Unable to get it to print out the number when the prompt is answered with negative one. It keeps asking for more numbers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Prompt</h2>

<script>
var sum=0;
var number = prompt("Please enter a number:");
while(number>-1)
prompt("Please enter a number:");
sum=number+sum;
if(number=-1) {
document.write(sum);
}
```

Comment: `number=-1` is assignment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are working on an assignment so I'll give you some poiters:

`number` is never getting changed, you need to assign it to what the user enters from within your loop, like you did with the previous prompt.

It looks like you can skip the first prompt, and only prompt inside the loop (as long as you remember to assign that value back to `number`).  Set `var number = 0` initally.

Single equal sign will do assignment.  So `if(number=-1)` will *set* the value of number to -1.

To do a comparison in an `if` statement, use triple equals.  You will always use triple equals when checking if something equals something else (all if statements)

(thanks @acn3) You also need braces to contain all the logic within your while loop, open brace before the prompt and close brace after the if statement.

Comment: They also need an open curly brace after the while's condition and a close curly brace after sum is changed.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way.

```js
var sum=0;
var number = 0
while(number != -1)
    {
  number = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number:"));

    if(number==-1) 
     document.write(sum);
    else
      sum= number + sum;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```